# DataFrame.drop_duplicates and DataFrame.drop not removing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have read in a csv into a pandas dataframe and it has five columns. Certain rows have duplicate values only in the second column, i want to remove these rows from the dataframe but neither drop nor drop_duplicates is working.

Here is my implementation:

```
#Read CSV
df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

print Series(df.b)

dropRows = []
#Sanitize the data to get rid of duplicates
for indx, val in enumerate(df.b): #for all the values
    if(indx == 0): #skip first indx
        continue

    if (val == df.b[indx-1]): #this is duplicate rtc value
        dropRows.append(indx)

print dropRows

df.drop(dropRows) #this doesnt work
df.drop_duplicates('b') #this doesnt work either

print Series(df.b)
```

when i print out the series df.b before and after they are the same length and I can visibly see the duplicates still. is there something wrong in my implementation?

Comment: drop and duplicates create new datafraames. So you want something like:`df = df.drop_duplicates('b')`

Comment: By default drop and in fact most pandas operations return a copy, for some and in fact these functions then can be passed the param `in_place=true` to perform the operation on the original df and not return a copy

Comment: I believe that the API was designed this way to ensure that original data in memory were not accidentally written over. It's kinda helpful, if one thinks about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `drop` and `drop_duplicates` creates a new DataFrame, unless provided with an inplace argument. All these options would work:

```
df = df.drop(dropRows)
df = df.drop_duplicates('b') #this doesnt work either
df.drop(dropRows, inplace = True)
df.drop_duplicates('b', inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the issue was that I was concatenating dfs with columns of different types:

```py
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1]], columns=['letter', 'code'])
s2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', '1']], columns=['letter', 'code'])
df = pd.concat([s1, s2])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# 2 rows
print(df)

# int
print(type(df.at[0, 'code']))
# string
print(type(df.at[1, 'code']))

# Fix:
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# 1 row
print(df)
```