# drop_duplicates not working in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, duplicates

The purpose of my code is to import 2 Excel files, compare them, and print out the differences to a new Excel file.

However, after concatenating all the data, and using the `drop_duplicates` function, the code is accepted by the console. But, when printed to the new excel file, duplicates still remain within the day.

Am I missing something? Is something nullifying the `drop_duplicates` function?

My code is as follows:

```
import datetime
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
#identify excel file paths
filepath = r"excel filepath"
filepath2 = r"excel filepath2"
#read relevant columns from the excel files
df1 = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheetname="Sheet1", parse_cols= "B, D, G, O")
df2 = pd.read_excel(filepath2, sheetname="Sheet1", parse_cols= "B, D, F, J")
#merge the columns from both excel files into one column each respectively
df4 = df1["Exchange Code"] + df1["Product Type"] + df1["Product Description"] + df1["Quantity"].apply(str)
df5 = df2["Exchange"] + df2["Product Type"] + df2["Product Description"] + df2["Quantity"].apply(str)
#concatenate both columns from each excel file, to make one big column containing all the data
df = pd.concat([df4, df5])
#remove all whitespace from each row of the column of data
df=df.str.strip()
df=["".join(x.split()) for x in df] 
#convert the data to a dataframe from a series
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': df}) 
#remove any duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)
#print to the console just as a visual aid
print(df)
#print the erroneous entries to an excel file
df.to_excel("Comparison19.xls")
```

Comment: hint: read the params `df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)`

Comment: From a cursory look, you don't save the modifications you do to `df` when you use the `drop_duplicates` method. You'll have to set `inplace` to True or reassign to the same variable name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataFrame.drop\_duplicates and DataFrame.drop not removing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695878/dataframe-drop-duplicates-and-dataframe-drop-not-removing-rows)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You've got `inplace=False` so you're not modifying `df`. You want either

```
 df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)
```

or

```
 df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)
```

Comment: Replacing inplace=False with inplace=True worked! Thanks Keith.

Answer (score 15):

I have just had this issue, and this was not the solution.

It may be in the docs - I admittedly havent looked - and crucially this is only when dealing with date-based unique rows: the 'date' column must be formatted as such.

If the `date` data is a pandas *object* dtype, the `drop_duplicates` will not work - do a `pd.to_datetime` first.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work: df['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df.index). I am still getting non-duplicate rows dropped.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a DatetimeIndex in your DataFrame this will **not** work

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)
```

Instead one can use:

```
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Like `drop_duplicates()`, [`pandas.Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) supports the `keep` argument which can be set to `first` (default), `last` or `False`.

**Note:** Make sure first the index is not of dtype `object` but `datetime64`, which you can check using `df.index`. You may need to convert the index first using

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I have tried making df=df.set_index('date_time') and then df=df[~df.index.duplicated()]. But I am still getting rows dropped that are not duplicated.

Comment: This also works for multiindex DataFrames with datetime parts

Comment: @WesleyKitlasten As BAC83 has commented, make sure the index is not of type _object_ but _datetime64_. You may need to convert the index first with `pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: *WORKED FOR ME - 2 steps:*

1 - make sure your index is pd.to_datetime(df.index)
2 - Use the df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

Comment: this works for keep="first", but how do you accomplish the same thing for keep="last"?

Comment: @MaxM. [pandas.Index.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) also supports the `keep` argument. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Might help anyone in the future.

I had a column with dates, where I tried to remove duplicates without success.
If it's not important to keep the column as a date for further operations, I converted the column from type object to string.

```
df = df.astype('str')
```

Then I performed @Keith answers

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)
```

Comment: Huge +1, was struggling to make sense of why I was still getting duplicate records. In my case, had a datetime field which I then changed to df['x'] = df['x'].dt.date. This worked, so I didn't have to convert to a string, but wouldn't have tested if this hadn't been pointed out. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)!. I agree with struggling with date variables so I'm happy to share ideas as I think dates is one of the more tricky aspects of coding.

Comment: This saved me. I used df.applymap(str) but of course same result

Answer (score 5):

The use of `inplace=False` tells pandas to return a new dataframe with duplicates dropped, so you need to assign that back to `df`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=False)
```

or `inplace=True` to tell pandas to drop duplicates in the current dataframe

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep="first", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a good place to put it. But I recently learned that `.drop_duplicates()` has to have a match in ALL subsets for dropping a row.

So for deleting multiple based on only the one value i used this code:

```
no_duplicates_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['email'], keep="first", inplace=False)                     # Delete duplicates in email
no_duplicates_df = no_duplicates_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['phonenumber'], keep="first", inplace=False) # Delete duplicates in phonenumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but a different reason.

After appending one dataframe to another I wanted to de-duplicate based on an id (integer). However, appending changed the type of that column to float and it did not work (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6485). I fixed it by running the following before running drop_duplicates:

`df = df.astype({'id': 'int64'})`