# why pandas read duplicates in .csv file then rename them?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook, duplicates

I am working with python and I read a file and I want to drop duplicates from the same questions but it keeps reading the duplicates with the name.1

for example: there is 2 of question1 it reads them question1 and question1.1

so when I use .drop_duplicates() it does not do anything, what is the problem here?

```
file = 'survey.csv'
responses = pd.read_csv(file,header=1)
responses.head()
responses.drop_duplicates()
```

here is a sample of the .cvs file

```
>         ,,,X,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
>     Timestamp,Email Address,,"Know about basic linear algebra and matrices operations (multiplication, add, transpose)?",Know how to
> apply differentiation and the chain rule?,Know how to apply
> differentiation and the chain rule?,"Know what is a probability
> distribution and density function, and how to sample it?","Know what
> is a probability distribution and density function, and how to sample
> it?",Know the difference between classification and regression?,Know
> the difference between training and testing data?,Know the difference
> between training and testing data?,Know what is a training loop and
> what is an epoch?,Know what is a batch?,Know what is
> regularization?,Know what is overfitting and underfitting?,Know what
> is a feature vector?,,,,
>     ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
>     10/14/2021 17:15:05,y.sedki@gmail.com,,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,,,,
>     10/14/2021 17:15:39,k.abdulaal@hotmail.com,,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,,,,
```

but the output after writing the code above is

> ```
> > Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?   Know how to
> > apply differentiation and the chain rule?.1
> ```

Comment: I don't think it will change `question1` to `question1.1` by itself. Are you sure it's not in the file? Show a sample of the file contents.

Comment: @Barmar column names are mangled to prevent duplicates by default. [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has `mangle_dupe_cols=True` It's unclear if the question means _column header_ duplicates or column data duplicates. I agree a sample of the csv would help. It's also unclear if we're not running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489758/15497888) depending on what we expect `responses.drop_duplicates()` to do

Comment: If your `header=1`. What's on the first line?

Comment: @Barmar here is a sample: ,,,X,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, Timestamp,Email Address,,"Know about basic linear algebra and matrices operations?",Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?,Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?,"Know what is a probability distribution and density function, and how to sample it?",

Comment: @HenryEcker I thought he was talking about duplicate data, not duplicate column names.

Comment: I agree. It's unclear. However, this behaviour of appending .1 is the exact behaviour of mangle columns. (which is only a guess based on what I know of the library and not supported by the question)

Comment: @labyrinth It is difficult to parse the csv in the comments. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69845202/edit) your question instead to provide additional clarifying details?

Comment: Where is `question1` in the sample CSV?

Comment: @HenryEcker done, there are more than one duplicated question I wanna drop but it keeps reading them all

Comment: @Barmar "Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?" for example, but it is not only for 1 question it is in the idea itself that it keeps renaming duplicates

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` is for dropping duplicate rows, not duplicate columns. Why do you have two columns for the same question?

Comment: @Barmar it is a training df from a random survey;  but thank you your comment made me search for dropping column duplicates and I reached a one line solution by df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately,  it did not work. Do u have any idea if there is another way to drop duplicate columns?

Comment: Python's csv module and the DictReader class can help you out; example below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider just specifying which columns *you know are duplicates* and specifically drop them in.  I don't know Pandas, but I imagine you can specify the columns in a row, maybe something like the following to cut out the fourth column (if that's a duplicate):

```py
row1 = responses[1]
values_I_care_about = row1[0:3] + row1[4:]
```

You can also use Python's **DictReader** class from the **csv** module to quickly de-dupe your data by column:

**main.py**

```py
import csv
import sys

with open('sample.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    row = next(reader)

writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=row.keys())
writer.writeheader()
```

I ran it on this sample data (copied your header, un-broke the newlines, and added a dummy row with a single value of 1):

```
Timestamp,Email Address,,"Know about basic linear algebra and matrices operations (multiplication, add, transpose)?",Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?,Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?,"Know what is a probability distribution and density function, and how to sample it?","Know what is a probability distribution and density function, and how to sample it?",Know the difference between classification and regression?,Know the difference between training and testing data?,Know the difference between training and testing data?,Know what is a training loop and what is an epoch?,Know what is a batch?,Know what is regularization?,Know what is overfitting and underfitting?,Know what is a feature vector?
1
```

I'm also using my favorite CSV command-line tool, [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv), to inspect the headers:

```
% python3 main.py | gocsv headers 
1: Timestamp
2: Email Address
3: 
4: Know about basic linear algebra and matrices operations (multiplication, add, transpose)?
5: Know how to apply differentiation and the chain rule?
6: Know what is a probability distribution and density function, and how to sample it?
7: Know the difference between classification and regression?
8: Know the difference between training and testing data?
9: Know what is a training loop and what is an epoch?
10: Know what is a batch?
11: Know what is regularization?
12: Know what is overfitting and underfitting?
13: Know what is a feature vector?
```

Because DictReader is reading column/header names as dict keys, you cannot have duplicate keys, so no duplicate columns/headers.  But you lose control over which duplicates are dropped.