# drop duplicates by value in csv python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to delete rows that have the same value (duplicate values) in specific column.

For example - I have the next df:

```
name, number, if_unique
1. name1, number1, unique
2. name2, number2, unique
3. name3, number3, not_unique
```

after removing duplicated by specific column (if_unique) the result will be:

```
3. name3, number 3, not_uniqe
```

I have tried so far:

```
df.drop_duplicates('git_url', keep=False)
```

Edit:

this line worked for me -

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset="if_unique", keep=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates('if_unique',keep=False)`

Comment: tried it, didn't work :(

Comment: Please provide a small workable example with your desired output, instead of abstract variables. If you want to delete all duplicates, it should work without the ```keep=False``` argument.

Comment: Did you want to do that `inplace=True`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drop\_duplicates not working in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46489695/drop-duplicates-not-working-in-pandas)

Comment: I want to remove both first and second  line (duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset="if_unique", keep=False, inplace=True)
```