# Pandas drop_duplicates not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas

I am executing the following command and though inplace is set as True, drop_duplicates is not working:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df
```

The output is as follows:

```
open    high    low close   ha_open ha_high ha_low  ha_close    ha_type
2008-11-01  8.900000    11.175000   7.450000    8.300000    8.90    11.175000   7.450000    8.30    Doji
2008-12-01  7.525000    9.400000    7.375000    7.825000    8.60    9.400000    7.375000    8.03    Doji
2009-01-01  7.850000    9.850000    6.600000    7.425000    8.32    9.850000    6.600000    7.93    Doji
2009-02-01  7.750000    10.000000   7.250000    8.075000    8.12    10.000000   7.250000    8.27    Doji
2009-03-01  8.250000    9.300000    6.750000    7.550000    8.20    9.300000    6.750000    7.96    Doji
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2023-03-01  67.150002   79.000000   63.049999   74.300003   81.98   81.980000   63.049999   70.88   Bear
2023-04-01  75.000000   86.000000   73.150002   83.550003   76.43   86.000000   73.150002   79.43   Doji
2023-05-01  83.550003   101.449997  81.250000   92.250000   77.93   101.449997  77.930000   89.62   Bull
2023-05-01  83.550003   101.449997  81.250000   92.250000   77.93   101.449997  77.930000   89.62   Bull
2023-06-01  92.300003   104.099998  89.500000   94.300003   83.78   104.099998  83.780000   95.05   Bull
177 rows × 9 columns
```

As it can be observed the exactly duplicate rows of 2023-05-01 is not removed.

Comment: Apparently it does not work directly for dates, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222264/13339621 .

Comment: Works fine with the provided example. Are you sure the floats are identical and not just close to each other? try rounding to a given precision before `drop_duplicates`.

Comment: Try df.reset_index() before dropping duplicates

Comment: @gtomer if it doesn't work with the dates as index, resetting the index shouldn't be better

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.loc['2023-05-01'].to_dict('list')`?

Comment: He complains that it leaves duplicate dates. If will not be as index, drop_duplicates will look at it

Comment: @gtomer, if you reset the index, this adds an extra constraint to drop duplicates. If no duplicates are found without the index, adding the index to it will no change that. If OP wants to drop the duplicated dates without considering the columns, then `out = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'], inplace=True)
```